# What is the proper word?

Tags: word-choice

I have a question....( referring to a car that is in storage 6 months of the year)  what is the proper word.    It is only "drove" half the year, or It is only "driven" half the year.

Answer (score 2):

"drove" is the Past Simple Active form.

So it's grammatically wrong here because in your case you need the Passive form (Past Participle).

So the grammatically correct is: 
"It is only driven (for) six months."

Or: ''I drove it (for) six months.''

Comment: And, syntactically, the correct use of the other tense would be *it drove half the year*. However, that doesn't make sense—unless it actually manages to drive itself. ;)